# Regex in PHP: Replacing text between strings

Tags: php, regex

Okay I have made some progress on a problem I am solving, but need some help with a small glitch.

I need to remove all characters from the filenames in the specific path `images/prices/` BEFORE the first digit, except for where there is `from_`, in which case remove all characters from the filename BEFORE `from_`.

Examples:

```
BEFORE                                AFTER
images/prices/abcde40.gif           > images/prices/40.gif
images/prices/UgfVe5559.gif         > images/prices/5559.gif
images/prices/wedsxcdfrom_88457.gif > images/prices/from_88457.gif
```

What I've done:

```
$pattern = '%images/(.+?)/([^0-9]+?)(from_|)([0-9]+?)\.gif%';
$replace = 'images/\\1/\\3\\4.gif';
$string = "AAA images/prices/abcde40.gif BBB images/prices/wedsxcdfrom_88457.gif CCC images/prices/UgfVe5559.gif DDD";
$newstring = str_ireplace('from_','733694521548',$string);
while(preg_match($pattern,$newstring)){
    $newstring=preg_replace($pattern,$replace,$newstring);
}
$newstring=str_ireplace('733694521548','from_',$newstring);
echo "Original:\n$string\n\nNew:\n$newstring";
```

My expected output is:

```
AAA images/prices/40.gif BBB images/prices/from_88457.gif CCC images/prices/5559.gif DDD"
```

But instead I am getting:

```
AAA images/prices/40.gif BBB images/from_88457.gif CCC images/5559.gif DDD
```

The `prices/` part of the path is missing from the last two paths.

Note that the `AAA`, `BBB` etc. portions are just placeholders. In reality the paths are scattered all across a raw HTML file parsed into a string, so we cannot rely on any pattern in between occurrences of the text to be replaced.

Also, I know the method I am using of substituting `from_` is hacky, but this is purely for a local file operation and not for a production server, so I am okay with it. However if there is a better way, I am all ears!

Thanks for any assistance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use lookaround assertions:

```
preg_replace('~(?<=/)(?:([a-z]+)(?=\d+\.gif)|(\w+)(?=from_))~i', '', $value);
```

**Explanation:**

```bash
(?<=/)          # If preceded by a '/':
(?:             # Begin group
 ([a-z]+)       #   Match alphabets from a-z, one or more times
 (?=\d+\.gif)   #   If followed followed by digit(s) and '.gif'
 |              #   OR
 (\w+)          #   Match word characters, one or more times
 (?=from_)      #   If followed by 'from_'
)               # End group
```

**Visualization:**

[image: Image from debuggex]

**Code:**

```
$pattern = '~(?<=/)(?:([a-z]+)(?=\d+\.gif)|(\w+)(?=from_))~i';
echo preg_replace($pattern, '', $string);
```

[**Demo**](https://eval.in/181119)

Comment: Thanks, but I cannot work with nice and clean arrays here - the problem is such that I need the replacement to work with all matching instances inside a long string.

Comment: @RC: It doesn't matter. It should work with a plain string as well. [See demo](https://eval.in/181107).

Comment: Yes it does! Sorry I had seen so many solutions with an array input that failed with a long string, so I didn't test it. Thanks so much! And also for the effort in mapping out the syntax - much appreciated!

Comment: Sorry, just realised something: how do I amend your pattern so that it ONLY replaces filenames within the `images/prices/` path, and ignores all other similar filenames in other paths?

Comment: @RC: Simply change the lookbehind to `(?<=images/prices/)`.

Comment: Ah yes just got it. Bingo. Thanks again!

Comment: Glad to have helped, @RC. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

```
$arr = array(
    'images/prices/abcde40.gif',
    'images/prices/UgfVe5559.gif',
    'images/prices/wedsxcdfrom_88457.gif'
);

foreach($arr as $str){
    echo preg_replace('#images/prices/.*?((from_|\d).*)#i','images/prices/$1',$str);
}
```

**[DEMO](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/783a43676dfcbe32023e435a6424c852c6072e14)**

## EDIT:

```
$str = 'AAA images/prices/abcde40.gif BBB images/prices/wedsxcdfrom_88457.gif CCC images/prices/UgfVe5559.gif DDD';

echo preg_replace('#images/prices/.*?((from_|\d).*?\s|$)#i','images/prices/$1',$str), PHP_EOL;
```

Comment: Thanks, but I cannot work with nice and clean arrays here - the problem is such that I need the replacement to work with all matching instances inside a long string.

Comment: @RC You can still use, kind of, the same regex. I updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this regex for replacement:

```
^(images/prices/)\D*?(from_)?(\d+\..+)$
```

And use this expression for replacement:

```
$1$2$3
```

#### [RegEx Demo](http://regex101.com/r/uP6iW6/1)

**Code:**

```
$re = '~^(images/prices/)\D*?(from_)?(\d+\..+)$~m'; 
$str = "images/prices/abcde40.gif\nimages/prices/UgfVe5559.gif\nimages/prices/wedsxcdfrom_88457.gif";     
$result = preg_replace($re, '$1$2$3', $str);
```

Comment: Thanks, but if I replace the line breaks with spaces, the code fails. Only the first item is replaced - the remaining two are not. I need every matching instance in a long string to be replaced. Any ideas?

Comment: Did you check my linked demo where all the images are getting replaced. You might be missing `m` flag.

Comment: I'm really bad with Regex! I tried running your code with the line breaks replaced with spaces and this is the result: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/2c22531490a5488b273b21aa9f131da2dd80db3b - the last two are not replaced.

Comment: In that case your regex will be: `$re = '~(images/prices/)\D*?(from_)?(\d+\..+)~'; `

Answer (score 0):

You can try with **Lookaround** as well. Just replace with blank string.

```
(?<=^images\/prices\/).*?(?=(from_)?\d+\.gif$)
```

[regex101 demo](http://regex101.com/r/yM8eU2/1)

Sample code: (directly from above site)

```
$re = "/(?<=^images\\/prices\\/).*?(?=(from_)?\\d+\\.gif$)/m";
$str = "images/prices/abcde40.gif\nimages/prices/UgfVe5559.gif\nimages/prices/wedsxcdfrom_88457.gif";
$subst = '';

$result = preg_replace($re, $subst, $str);
```

---

If string is not multi-line then use `\b` as word boundary instead of `^` and `$` to match start and end of the line/string.

```
(?<=\bimages\/prices\/).*?(?=(from_)?\d+\.gif\b)
```

Comment: Thanks, but if I replace the line breaks with spaces, the code fails and only displays the last item. I need every matching instance in a long string to be replaced. Any ideas?

Comment: Thanks. I'm really bad with Regex syntax, so may be missing something, but I set `$re = "(?<=\bimages\/prices\/).*?(?=(from_)?\d+\.gif\b)";` and ran the code but got a `Unknown modifier '.'` error.